# My program is terminated

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to take string input from console and store them in ArrayList.
After that, I am adding all the numbers that are entered to get their sum
I am not understanding what am I doing wrong, please suggest

```
package mysmallprograms;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**   
 * my project to build a calculator
 *
 */    
public class Calculator {

    public static int add(ArrayList<String> numbers)
    {
        int sum=0;
        System.out.println("inside function add");
        if(numbers.isEmpty()==true) {
            System.out.println("empty string");
            return sum;
        } else {
            System.out.println("String arraylist to be summed");
            Iterator<String> it=numbers.iterator();

            while(it.hasNext()) {
                int elem=Integer.parseInt(( it.next()));
                sum+=elem;
                System.out.println("calculating sum");
                return sum;                     
            }

            return sum;
        }                               
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> numbers= new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("enter the numbers you want to add press enter after every number:");

        try {
            while(input.hasNextLine()) {
                String s=input.nextLine();

                if(s.equals("*")) {   
                    System.exit(0);
                    input.close();                          
                } else {   
                    System.out.println("adding element in arraylist");
                    numbers.add(s);
                }                   
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {                             
            System.out.println("calling calculator ");
            int sum=add(numbers);
            System.out.println("Sum of numbers : "+sum);
        }
    }       
}
```

I am trying to take string input from console and store them in ArrayList.
After that, I am adding all the numbers that are entered to get their sum
I am not understanding what am I doing wrong, please suggest

Comment: Any errors ? stack trace ?

Comment: Consider fixing your indentation if you would like people to try and read your code.

Comment: There's a `return` statement in the `while` loop, so it will never execute more than once.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ no error just the program is getting terminated

Comment: @Henrik I took your suggestion and deleted return from while but still it is not working

Comment: @khelwood Thanks for your suggestion I will surely do that from now onwards

Comment: there is no termination condition for while loop. it just keeps adding numbers infinitely...

Comment: A minor detail: The check for whether the arraylist is empty is unnecessary. You can get an iterator from an empty collection, it will just not provide you with any elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package mysmallprograms;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;



/**

 * my project to build a calculator
 *
 */

    public class Calculator {
        public static int add(ArrayList<String> numbers)
        {   int sum=0;
            System.out.println("inside function add");
            if(numbers.isEmpty()==true)
                {System.out.println("empty string");
               }
            else
                {
                 System.out.println("String arraylist to be summed");
                 Iterator<String> it=numbers.iterator();

                 while(it.hasNext())
            {   int elem=Integer.parseInt(( it.next()));
                sum+=elem;
                System.out.println("calculating sum");
            }
        }
    return sum;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> numbers= new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("enter the numbers you want to add press enter after every number:");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    try {
        while(num > 0 )
        { num--;
          String s=input.nextLine();
          System.out.println("adding element in arraylist");
          numbers.add(s);
        }
    }
       catch(Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
       }
        finally
        {
        System.out.println("calling calculator ");
        int sum=add(numbers);
        System.out.println("Sum of numbers : "+sum);
        }
    }


}
```

Sorry, I haven't fixed the indentation. Your while loop was running in infinite loop, made some other minor changes as well.
Hope it helps, Cheers!

Comment: One more thing I dont want to give number of numbers to be added but I want any input that user provides to instruct the program that now add my numbers I tried that using * but not working for me in the original program

Comment: You could use something like this: [link](https://repl.it/repls/WelltodoFearlessXantusmurrelet)